# Pedagogical reference to learn how to work with CFTs?

Tags: conformal-field-theory, ads-cft

I know very little about AdS/CFT, but I am considering looking more into quantum gravity for future research topics.  From those of you who have already "conquered" AdS/CFT, I was wondering what the best pedagogical reference(s) is (are) to understanding how the AdS/CFT correspondence is set up.

I am specifically looking for a pedagogical reference that could help me understand how equations 6 and 7 are derived in [this paper](https://arxiv.org/pdf/0911.3893.pdf), which is one of several papers that has sparked my interest in this topic.

Comment: Have you tried looking at arXiv:hep-th/9902121 which the authors cite before equations 6 and 7?

Comment: Apart from the reference the authors cited, which I believe should address the specific equations you want, there are several very good resources to learn AdS/CFT: the lecture notes by Penedones: https://arxiv.org/abs/1608.04948 are a great one. Maybe you can start there and the references he cite.

Comment: I did look at arXiv:hep-th/9902121, but they do not explicitly derive those equations.  I will take a look at the lecture notes by Penedones.